# Add an image file to existing javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a template with existing javascript.  The mobile menu "icon" is actually a dropdown that has the word "MENU" in it.  This is old style in my opinion and I'd like to change that to the standard 3 bars for a mobile menu.

The section of the javascript that brings this up is:

```
if ($nav.is('ul,ol')) {

    if (settings.header) {
      $select.append(
        $('<option/>').text('MENU')
      );
    }
```

Is it possible to add .src("img/mobilemenubars.png") or something to this effect to replace the .text('MENU') section?  I can provide the entire javascript but I am not sure that is necessary.  Or is it?

Comment: option elements do not support images in a select so the answer is no. Some browser might let you set a background image, but I believe that is **very** limited.

Comment: Your best bet for putting any sort of image/icon/etc. into an <option> element is to use the unicode character.

Comment: If you really need image in option menu, you should try some JS plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using unicode characters and the Font Awesome font-family. [Here is a DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jabacabomi/edit?html,css,js,output)

Here is the [Font Awesome cheat sheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) for unicode icons

```css
select {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <select>
    <option>&#xf0c9; Menu</option>
    <option>&#xf040; Pencil</option>
    <option>&#xf072; Vacation</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```